# Enable CORS on JSON API Wordpress

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, cors

I have this wordpress site with a plugin called JSON API. This plugin provides a JSON format for the content that is in the wordpress. I was able to enable CORS on the wordpress by adding header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on the php header. But when I tried the url that the JSON API plugin provides the CORS does not work anymore.

This is the wordpress site were I'm doing the tests... I used the test cors website to check if it was working and it is...
http://kiwa-app.loading.net/

But when I try with the url that the JSON api provides me, is not working anymore. I'm still have the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
http://kiwa-app.loading.net/?json=info

I will apreciate some help thanks!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out an easy way...

You just have to add:

```
     <? header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

On the file api.php, this file is located in wp-content/plugins/json-api/singletons/api.php

I hope it helps more people with the same problem!

Comment: For any one confused like me add this as the very first line before `<?php` with no blank lines.

Comment: Should not be editing the core files, using a filter is better.

Comment: This line change is deleted everytime wordpress gets updated, downvoted.

Comment: As @IvanCastellanos has said, this is really dirty fix that will be lost when WordPress is updated

Comment: `wp-content/plugins/json-api/singletons/api.php` not found in mine.
found content related to a rest api in `/wp-includes/rest-api` but idk if that's what needs to be changed.

Comment: Can you please tell me which plugin need to install from below list?
1)JSON API Auth
2)JSON API User
3)JSON API Cincopa

Comment: terrible advice, NEVER edit core files.

Answer (score 50):

I've used a few different WordPress API's - but for those of you using the 'official' [WP-API](http://wp-api.org/), I had much trouble with this CORS --- and what I found was *that between the .htaccess approach* and a few others I stumbled upon... adding this to your theme functions.php worked best.

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Be sure not to use any combinations of these ( .htaccess, header.php, api.php, functions.php ) as it will be angry at you.

Comment: This worked for v1, but I just came across this again - and I'm not having any luck with v2 yet.

Comment: Works with Wordpress API V2. Best solution I could find.

Comment: This is the only solution working for me. Some server doesn't allow you to set CORS in htacces

Comment: This worked for me! A good way to test and make sure it is working is to check the headers — Advanced Rest Client is a good tool.

Comment: this has not worked for me in Wordpress V5, I've checked the headers and my header is not in there.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St - bummer! I haven't used this in a while - / or haven't upgraded any of the apps using it. I know that wp-json is now in core. Some things may have changed. If you figure it out - be sure to come back and add it here. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702061/enable-cors-on-json-api-wordpress/29201101?noredirect=1#comment96621076_29201101

Comment: @sheriffderek these changes here actually changed my headers. However, didn't fix my specific problem.

Comment: this has not worked for me in Wordpress V5, the solution is in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642286/2400373

Answer (score 11):

Using Wordpress 5.2.3 - whilst using GET and POST externally, the following finally opened sesame for me. I tried all of the answers above (to no avail) before finding this solution that worked for my case.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    add_action( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function () {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, X-WP-Wpml-Language', true );
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    } );
}, 15 );
```

Hopefully WordPress will have an official doggy door-flap for CORS control in the future.

Comment: Where exactly did you add this file.

Comment: @ChinomsoJohnson functions.php inside your theme folder

Answer (score 9):

Before the response is sent to the browser, we can run [two action hooks](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/json-api/tags/1.1.1/singletons/api.php#L49) and insert a new `header()`:

```
do_action("json_api", $controller, $method);
do_action("json_api-{$controller}-$method");
```

The first one runs on every method, and the second one is to target specific methods. Here's an implementation of the first one, with a commented way to find the second:

```
add_action( 'json_api', function( $controller, $method )
{
    # DEBUG
    // wp_die( "To target only this method use <pre><code>add_action('$controller-$method', function(){ /*YOUR-STUFF*/ });</code></pre>" );

    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The actions for json-rest-api plugin are: json_insert_post, json_insert_user, json_query_navigation_headers, wp_json_server_before_serve

Answer (score 9):

Now that REST API is merged with core, we can use the `rest_api_init` action.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function()
{
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
} );
```

Comment: which file do I add this to ?

Comment: @HaseebBurki The above code extends an action. You can either add this code to the functions.php file of your theme or in a new custom plugin.

Answer (score 6):

WordPress 5 (4.4+ actually) can handle it via WP Headers:

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_headers', 'send_cors_headers', 11, 1 );
function send_cors_headers( $headers ) {
    $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_ORIGIN' ];
    return $headers;
}
```

Note that this will allow access from ANY source. For security you should try to do something like set an array of allowed domains that can make the request to your WordPress site and short-circuit the allow CORS if the domain making the request is not in the allowed list:

```
add_filter( 'wp_headers', 'send_cors_headers', 11, 1 );
function send_cors_headers( $headers ) {
    $allowed_domains = array( 'https://my.okdomain.com' , 'http://anothergoodone.com');
    if ( ! in_array( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_ORIGIN' ] , $allowed_domains ) ) return $headers;
    $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_ORIGIN' ];
    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for where to put this code?

Comment: Hi, You need to add this code in function.php file

Comment: Hi everyone, 
From Dashboard
- Apperance -> Theme Editor
- From right side check if the theme is selected - Open function.php from the file directory
- Add the code at last of the file

Answer (score 2):

In wordpress goto plugins > JSON API > Edit

**From the right hand file selection select**

json-api/singletons/api.php

**You will need to add the following line**

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Your code should look similar to this once done. **Adding this line anywhere else might not work as expected.**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
class JSON_API {

  function __construct() {
    $this->query = new JSON_API_Query();
    $this->introspector = new JSON_API_Introspector();
    $this->response = new JSON_API_Response();
    add_action('template_redirect', array(&$this, 'template_redirect'));
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'admin_menu'));
    add_action('update_option_json_api_base', array(&$this, 'flush_rewrite_rules'));
    add_action('pre_update_option_json_api_controllers', array(&$this, 'update_controllers'));
  }

  function template_redirect() {
```

Comment: What if you dont have json api installed?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still facing any issue after trying all of the above code(making changes in `funtions.php` in your theme) / `.htaccess` way, then probably  this problem is with your hosting service provider.

I have tried all the possible things and wasted my two days on this problem and came to know that the problem is due to `infinityfree . com` (free hosting service provider).

Reference:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-api-blocks-post-by-cors-policy/
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-api-blocks-post-by-cors-policy-2/

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who is having this issue with **multiple origins**

In your server hosting your wordpress site, navigate to ../wp-content/plugins/json-rest-api and from here  open the plugin.php file.

In this function

```
function json_send_cors_headers( $value ) {..}
```

Change the header

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
```

To

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
```

Hope this helps anyone who was incurring the same issues as I.

Answer (score -2):

The solution works with WordPress 5.1.1 and Gutenberg

```
add_filter('rest_url', function($url) {
    $url = str_replace(home_url(), site_url(), $url);
    return $url;
});
```

Comment: This solution is the way to go when you're running the Wordpress admin on a different domain than the main website. For example running just the Wordpress admin on a  subdomain.

Answer (score -5):

In WordPress project go to following file and do like this:

In `wp-includes/rest-api.php` change:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin );
```

to:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
```

In `wp-includes/http.php` change:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin );
```

to:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
```

Comment: you don't want to make changes to the `wp-includes` folder as it'll probably be erased if you update.

Comment: Never make changes to wp core files. Anyone looking at this question, do not use this answer, it's dangerous.