# WordPress JSON API - Request Header Error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, wordpress

I'm working with the WordPress JSON API plugin to make requests to get posts and etc from my blog.

When I try to access a simple url from browser it works perfectly, but when I try to access from my Ionic application this following erros occurs:

```
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Do I need to do something from my WP blog to allow it?

Comment: i found out this answer, it should be helpful [Enable CORS on JSON API Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702061/enable-cors-on-json-api-wordpress)

Comment: Hey @StefanoSaitta thank you, but I checked and none of the stuff over there worked for me, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to a **cross-origin request**. So try adding the below **headers** in your `functions.php` file.

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Make sure that you haven't already used header in another file, or you will get a nasty error.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your tip, but unfortunately it doesn't worked. It still showing the same error.