# Wordpress REST API app key

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, api, react-redux

I'm thinking of making a [frontend application](https://github.com/andrixb/wp-react-redux-rest-api/) based on Wordpress and the [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) and I'm not a security expert. 
I noticed that by default [I can fetch the content without having an auth key for the application](https://github.com/andrixb/wp-react-redux-rest-api/blob/master/src/actions/index.jsx), so basically everyone can get the content without being authorized (and I am giving for granted that at least I cannot post anything if I am not logged in). 
Is that normal?

Does anyone know how I can restrict this behaviour by creating a key?

Thank you very much

Comment: I found this link which points out as well the same issue: https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-security/wordpress-rest-api-and-the-security-worries/

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're attempting you'll need a healthy understanding of JSON Web Tokens and two plugins.

The first plugin is [My Private Site](https://localhost/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=jonradio-private-site&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550). This plugin will prevent users from viewing any content on the website front end. Turning Wordpress into a content editor with only a REST API available to access content.

The second plugin you'll want is [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/). This will allow you to require JWT authentication anytime a user requests data from the RestApi. Here's an article from AAM on how to set up [JWT in Wordpress](https://aamplugin.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-wordpress-jwt-authentication).

I hope this helps :D

Answer (score -1):

Just enable CORS in the `header.php` [Enable CORS on JSON API Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702061/enable-cors-on-json-api-wordpress)

---

The following can be a useful consideration even though:

By keeping to what it is stated here https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-security/wordpress-rest-api-and-the-security-worries/:

> the information that is available 
>   via the WordPress REST API is already available to the public via other > means, such as the website itself and RSS. The only difference between the 
>   front-end of the website, RSS and the REST API is the way the data is 
>   presented.

One one the questions at the bottom of this article is about DoS attacks and the answer is the following:

> As explained in the post the data available through REST API is already 
>   publicly available, so as much as an attacker can create a DoS-type attack 
>   on the REST API he can do the same on the website. Actually, requesting 
>   something from the REST API is more efficient than when requesting it from the interface since the request and response contain much less data (the interface itself) so in a way, it is more efficient.