# CORS Access error while calling wordpress user api via ionic3

Tags: wordpress, api, ionic-framework, ionic2, cors

I am trying to invoke wordpress rest api's in ionic application most api's seem to work fine but while invoking some api's mostly the setter api's i get the CORS error however they work perfectly when invoked via web. Most of the solutions available online are for localhost but since i need to implement the same on online resources they are not useful unable to get any clue about the rectification also since some api may involve limited access i can not prefer any third party proxy sites.the error i am getting is as follows:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://test.oiamigotech.com/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=dsfsdfdsdfssdf&password=sdfsdfsdfsdf&insecure=cool. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Comment: You have to all header via php

Comment: Ionic have its own [proxy](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/). Give it a try

Comment: please explain how can i use the ionic proxies ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the following issue by adding a header to allow cross origin request in the header of the api file of the plug-in as indicated in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702061/enable-cors-on-json-api-wordpress).

All I had to do is to add the following to the header of api code

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
```