# CORS Api with symfony

Tags: symfony, cors, cross-domain, symfony-2.1

I should make cross domain API with Symfony.
There is some bundle for that?

I have tried FOS Rest Bundle but did not seem have solved my problem.

Comment: look at this one https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

Comment: Check out the API platform bundle too.

Comment: "my problem" - what problem? Its easy to guess, but we should not be forced to guess at first place. -1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I advise you to use NelmioCorsBundle:

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

This bundle  allows you to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers with ACL-style per-URL configuration.

Is very useful for CORS problem

Comment: "Is very useful for CORS problem" I wouldn't say that CORS is a problem, it would be a problem without it!

Answer (score 11):

I used `Symfony 5` and `Wordpress` this code in the file `public/index.php` works perfectly.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
```

Also, I remove package `cors` .. This Bundle doesn't work for me

Comment: Genius. I had the same problem with Nelmio cors bundle not adding the headers

This solved it for me!

Comment: At what point of code did you insert these lines? I tried in many positions and it did not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you have to use in the header of code

Comment: Using 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' you are disabling CORS checking. 
Citation from Wikipedia:
If a site specifies the header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:*" third-party sites may be able to carry out privileged actions and retrieve sensitive information. Even if it does not, attackers may be able to bypass any IP-based access controls by proxying through users' browsers.

Comment: @Dominik The wikipedia excerpt you gave above talks about `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` and not `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. AFAIK, setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to an appropriate value does not cause any security issues.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure that's the right way, but I resolved for me:

1. Create new event subscriber (like `ResponseSubscriber`)
2. Listen `KernelEvents::RESPONSE` event
3. In your handler add the following:

```php
if ($event->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
    $event->setResponse(
            new Response('', 204, [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'DNT, X-User-Token, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 1728000,
                'Content-Type' => 'text/plain charset=UTF-8',
                'Content-Length' => 0
            ])
        );
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

or

if you want to write a cors package for yourself, here some tips:

- the 'to Checked' Origin will be automaticly embedded by any browser in HTTP_ORIGIN
- do not use a sole '*' wildcard
- you can cut of the request processing early if u use a request & response listener (if you want)
- do not only send it with OPTIONS methods (some browser may want it in GET or even POST requests.)

---

manage your Origin cors list in some config yaml files for example.
and validate the HTTP_ORIGIN if it matches your cors list. then send the HTTP_ORIGIN AS "VALID" back.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: THE_HTTP_ORIGIN_HERE`

+ the other Access-Control header.
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for more in depth information.

---

in the end, this mostly the same workflow that  https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle uses.
my advice: safe your time ;)

**TLDR**; don't take cors lightly by just use a wildcard, over a bad cors implementation every attacker site can fish a active session from your users.

- step1: user uses your API, has a session cookie,
- step2: user visits a random site, which embed code who just requested the browser to trigger a request directly to your api with the cookie credentals.
- step3: your api must detect this as a attack and not answer with a *.

the victim browser, its not possible to send a forged HTTP_ORIGIN via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

#### Serving static files

Be careful when serving static files as mentionned in [NelmioCorsBundle documentation](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle#features).

> Configured at the PHP/application level. This is convenient but it
> also means that any request serving static files and not going through
> Symfony will not have the CORS headers added, so if you need to serve
> CORS for static files you probably should rather configure these
> headers in your web server

For those of you who are using [Api platform](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/releases) and therefore a [caddy server](https://caddyserver.com/).

You can edit your `Caddyfile` with the [`header`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/header) directive to set a default value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```
header ?Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
```

You can also use env var:

`.env`

```
WEB_APP_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

`Caddyfile`

```
header ?Access-Control-Allow-Origin "{$WEB_APP_URL}"
```