# Symfony api, Delete request not working with angular client

Tags: angular, symfony

I'm developing a symfony API and an angular client and I would like to do an http delete request. I have already done get methods and they're working properly. However I can't figure out why the delete is not working when I call it from my angular web-page (It is working just fine with postman, [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J2iI.png)).

This is my symfony method :

```
/**
 * @Route("/API/cours/{id}/delete", name="delete_cours",methods={"DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteCours($id,CoursRepository $repo,  EntityManagerInterface $manager){
    $exists = 'no';
    if($cours = $repo->find($id)) {
        $existe = 'yes';
        $manager->remove($cours);
        $manager->flush();
    }
    $response = new Response('{ "id" : '. $id .' '. $existe.'  }');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
}
```

In angular, I created a service and the delete function is this :

```
deleteUnCours(id){
    return this.http.delete('https://127.0.0.1:8000/API/cours/' + id + '/delete');   }
```

My component code looks like this :

```
supprimer() {
    this.coursService.deleteUnCours(this.lecours.id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('deleted');
    });
  }
```

In the console I get the error

> CORS header : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing

However if I replace all the "delete" with "get" it is working correctly without an error ?

Comment: What you have to do in general is search about CORS & symphony

Comment: The browser will send a pre-flight OPTIONS request to the server, and **that** request should have the appropriate CORS headers as well. Do not reinvent the wheel, just install [nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) and let it handle CORS for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400213/cors-api-with-symfony

Comment: It will work through postman (or curl) because direct request won't perform CORS checks.

Comment: Ok, I installed [nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) and it worked !  Thanks !!!