# Wordpress PHP proper way to select row from table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve data from data wp database table via REST API.But i am getting error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at {.rest route..} has been blocked by CORS policy...`

My database quesry is

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->TableName() . "` WHERE `ID`= `" . $id . "` ");
```

But if i call like below, it works

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->TableName() . "`");
```

Here `$id` is ok `$id = $postdata->get_param('id');`
id is being sent to rest route.I think there is a problem in preparing `$wpdb`

Comment: I think you are missing something while getting the $id can you send your code by how you are getting the $id?

Comment: _“I think there is a problem in preparing $wpdb”_ - the error message you quoted has nothing to do directly with any database query; it is because you are trying to make a cross-domain request via client-side JavaScript, without the receiving end explicitly permitting this. (If the database query was faulty, that could lead to a 500 error or otherwise prevent that the necessary CORS headers are sent. But what exactly the reason is, is rather impossible to tell with the mere snippet you have shown us.)

Comment: @misorude Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://thefoody.kaziwood.com/wp-json/restaurant/v1/restaurants' from origin 'http://localhost:7770' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Please properly explain the actual scenario here. Is this just a request from localhost right now because you are testing something - and later it will be made under the same domain? Or is this explicitly, deliberately a cross-domain request? And if the latter, have you researched what you need to do to enable this …?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702061/enable-cors-on-json-api-wordpress