# multisite Wordpress API CORS issue with headers set in theme (v5)

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-theming, fetch, wordpress-rest-api

I have a React app which calls a Wordpress v5 API.

```
const api = `${WAPI}`;
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
} ;

fetch(api, {
  headers: headers
})
.then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
})
.then(this.handleposts)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

}

Which returns this error in my development tools' console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/firstcivdivcareers/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

I used to call a single Wordpress site API but now it doesn't' work. I assumed Wordpress API would work with cross-origin domain calls to be used as a third-party service.

I added changes to the theme's `functions.php`. When I go to my site in the browser and check the header's in dev tool console. I can see I sent my response with the proper headers. However, doesn't work the same when I call through my JS's fetch call.

Changes added to `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Only allow GET requests
 */
function add_cors_http_header(){

   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Locate the file in your wordpress code which is serving the API.

You just have to add at the start of that file:

```
 <? header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

Edit:

Instead of editing the core files, the better option is to use the filter as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702061/enable-cors-on-json-api-wordpress) thread. You can put the following code in your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('init', 'add_cors_header');
function add_cors_header() {
    header(...);
}
```

Comment: That's what I don't know. Where is it serving the API from? It's Wordpress 5. That allows all domains right? Or all HTTP verbs? Can I just set it for `GET` requests?

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue as well with my Vue.js code. This is what I added to my GET request and I have had no further issues: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` and it immediately precedes the URL:

let url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?&markdown=true&page=1';

I hope that helps!

Comment: so to route to a second service? There's definitely a way to configure this if I own the servers. I shouldn't need a second service. Wouldn't that slow down my application in production?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St I have not had any issues thus far, but I am not in production yet. Seems like that is another question for the group -- I do not know.

Comment: I ended up not needing it. Did a fresh install and just went up from single site to multisite. I suspect some meddling of mine caused the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this MS Edge plugin t quickly disable Cors.

[CORS Unblock - Microsoft Edge Addons](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cors-unblock/hkjklmhkbkdhlgnnfbbcihcajofmjgbh)

It will work just fine :)