# Fetching wp_mail has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm building a headless wordpress site with Nextjs. I'm trying to make an api call to my wordpress CMS.

When fetching data from wordpress I can't get pass the cors. Couldn't really find a way to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my api call. Ive been trying to do it like this, but still got the CORS error.

```
$headers = array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *; Content-Type: application/json; Accept: application/json');

wp_mail('test@mail.com', 'subject', 'msg', $headers);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is? How did you arrive at the conclusion that CORS is causing issues here? CORS is a front-end security mechanism designed to protect browser users; CORS should have ZERO effect on your ability to call an API from a back-end service with PHP. "*When fetching data from wordpress I can't get pass the cors*" The code you've provided does absolutely no fetching of any sort; have you pasted the wrong code?

Comment: @esqew — The OP said the call from coming from Next.js (which is a framework for creating SPAs backed by SSR), so the request is coming from JS which might run on the browser or a server.

Comment: @Quentin Fair point; in my interpretation of the question as written I would imagine the inclusion of the term "*headless... site*" precludes any sort of browser-based execution. Further, if the issue is indeed on the front-end, the OP's inclusion of PHP code further is confusing at best.

Comment: @esqew — a headless wordpress site is one in which WordPress isn't used to generate the user-centric website. Instead you use the WordPress admin site as a CMS and access the data from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few months ago.

Fixed it by adding the following code to the functions.php

```
  // Allow from any origin
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
  }

  // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
      // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the headers you are dealing with are SMTP headers. They should not go anywhere near the `wp_mail` function.

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) response headers (`Access-Control-Allow-*`) are **HTTP response headers**.

Generally with PHP, you need to add them to the HTTP response with [the `header()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Since you are using WordPress (which I'm not hugely familiar with), look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520952/19068) as it seems to wrap itself around the normal headers API.

`Content-Type: application/json` might an HTTP request **or** response header. It isn't clear from the context as your code snippet doesn't include anything to read the request body or generate the response body.

`Accept: application/json` is an HTTP request header and needs to be sent from the browser to the server. You shouldn't set it in PHP at all.

Comment: Ah this makes sense, I will try this. Thanks!