Best Practices for Handling Nonce and CORS in Next.js with Client and Server Components
I am developing a Next.js application that interacts with the Woocommerce Store API, which requires a nonce header for all POST requests to mutate data. The nonce is provided in the response headers from the API and can be stored on the client.
Currently, I use Server Components to pre-render pages like a product listing, fetching data without requiring nonce tokens as shown in the following example:
async function getProducts() {
  const response = await fetch('https://my-example-store.local/wp-json/wc/store/v1/products');
  if (!response.ok) { throw new Error('Failed to fetch data'); }
  return response.json();
}

interface Product {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  sku: string,
}

const Products = async () => {
  const products: Product[] = await getProducts();
  return (
    <>
      {products.map(product => (
        <div key={product.sku}>
          <div>{product.name}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Products;

This setup works well for display purposes. However, I want to add an "Add to cart" button that requires a POST request with the nonce token in the headers. Here's the client component for the button:
"use client"

async function addToCart({id, variation}: {id: number, variation:string}) {
  // API-call with nonce token
}

export default function Button({ id, variation }: { id: number, variation: string }) {
  const handleEvent = async () => {
    await addToCart({id, variation})
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleEvent()}>Add to cart</button>
  );
}

Since this involves client-side scripting, it appears I'm facing a CORS issue. Additionally, I need advice on efficiently managing and storing the nonce token, initially obtained from server responses.
I've tried using axios interceptors and cookies but faced difficulties in managing tokens differently for server and client requests, and modifying cookies seems only possible in server actions or route handlers.
Can anyone provide insights or best practices on how to handle this setup efficiently, particularly for managing the nonce token and overcoming CORS restrictions?

"Since this involves client-side scripting, it appears I'm facing a CORS issue" - Do you actually get a CORS error in your console? If not, then you aren't facing a CORS issue...

I have zero familiarity with Woocomerce, but I feel confident to say that your browser-based JS should never communicate with Woocomerce directly - instead your own web-service (i.e. your server-side NextJS code) should be responsible for all requests to Woocomerce, including those initiated by your own users (i.e. by proxying them).

CORS and handling nonces are two completely different problems to have. The site expects one question per question. 1. If you have a CORS issue, then you've not adequately described that such that it is answerable. 2. If you have to do something with nonces, you also need to adequately describe the problem. Asking for "best practices" is not a specific enough query: describe what you're trying to do and what issues you face/want to overcome. 3. Again ask for one thing here. Not random combinations of topics.

Regarding CORS, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702061/1427878

@Dai using WordPress as a "headless CMS" is a pretty common use case, and having a frontend directly communicate with the WP REST API in such a situation, is pretty usual practice, I think. "your browser-based JS should never communicate with Woocomerce directly" - why not? As long as everything is properly protected by nonces, I don't see the harm.

@CBroe The OP's post gave me the impression that they have something like a bearer-token / access-token or API-key to allow requests to the upstream service (Woocommerce) - so if browser-clients were making those requests then the OP's server-side code would need to expose protected-secrets to visitor browser clients - if that's not the case then I enjoy being corrected because it means I learned something new :3
